# Looping through elements - how to avoid "(var) is defined but not used" errors?

Tags: jquery, jshint

This is my code:

```
$.each($('.pages a[href!="#"]'), function (idx, elem) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    // other code
})
```

So basically, I'm using JQuery's `.each` to loop through the selected elements, but I'm using `$(this)` to access each element's attribute. JSHint complains about this, saying that `elem` and `idx` are defined but never used.

Is there another way to go about this without running into such errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to include them at all if they aren't used:

```
$.each($('.pages a[href!="#"]'), function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    // other code
})
```

Note that best practice for `each()` when used on a collection of elements is to use it on the jQuery object directly:

```
$('.pages a[href!="#"]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    // other code
})
```